# How to loop over a PySpark dataframe and print first 5 iterations?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that consists of one column and ten rows. I dropped the other columns in my code above.
This is what it looks like:

```
+--------------------+
|          movieTitle|
+--------------------+
|Across the Sea of...|
|Dog of Flanders, ...|
|      Bootmen (2000)|
|Relax... It's Jus...|
|Mating Habits of ...|
|        Belly (1998)|
|       Taffin (1988)|
|Love and Other Ca...|
|Shattered Image (...|
|Price Above Rubie...|
+--------------------+
```

I need to print out the first 5 rows with an index. The format is should be as follows:

```
Movies recommended for you:
1: Silence of the Lambs, The (1991)
2: Saving Private Ryan (1998)
3: Godfather, The (1972)
4: Star Wars: Episode 6 - A New Hope (1977)
5: Shawshank Redemption, The (1994)
```

It doesn't have to be those exact movies, just that format. I've tried changing it to an RDD and a pandas dataframe and iterating over them but I got errors with both. Is there any simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collect()` to create a list of the values in the `movieTitle` column and then simply iterate over it:

```
movies_list = df.select("movieTitle").collect()

n = 5
for i in range(n):
    print(str("%s: %s" % (i+1,movies_list[i][0])))
```

Output:

```
1: Silence of the Lambs, The (1991)
2: Saving Private Ryan (1998)
3: Godfather, The (1972)
4: Star Wars: Episode 6 - A New Hope (1977)
5: Shawshank Redemption, The (1994)
```

If you want to add an index to your pyspark dataframe, you can use `row_number`. (I'm using a window without partitions which should be ok for your data)

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, col, concat, lit

w = Window().orderBy("movieTitle")
df = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(w)).withColumn("movieTitle",\
         concat(col("row_num"), lit(": "), col("movieTitle"))).drop('row_num')

movies_list = df.select("movieTitle").collect()

n = 5
for i in range(n):
    print(movies_list[i][0])
```